# Querying a database through a website

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm relatively new to working with databases and am struggling to work out how to edit and display the database tables on my main index.php file.

I have managed to get the table linked locally using phpmyadmin.

**My goal is to have a user enter in a html form an item they would like to add to the database table, and then print out this new updated table below.**

I have the form setup as so below, but have no idea how to display it correctly on my webpage

Please enter item to add to the database:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="additem" id="additem" value="">
</form>
```

Really appreciate any help with this :)

Comment: So what's stopping you? This is a pretty standard thing. Be specific.

Comment: Internet is __full__ of manuals how to work with databases in php. No one will write another one here.

Comment: I'm struggling with the actual php code as I've had next to no experience with it. I don't know how to call on and edit the table itself through my main webpage

Comment: I'd suggest starting with some PHP tutorials in the case. SO shouldn't be your first port of call.

Comment: SO should be like a last resort when all fails.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change the method to POST. Then include a php file for the action. i.e. : form.php

In the form.php file, write your INSERT query to the database table. In this case,
INSERT INTO (table name) VALUES additem;